# asp.net application while deploying in IIS7 server error - cannot find table 0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I tried deploying an ASP.NET application in IIS server 7. I am using Windows 7. While deploying i am getting the error "Cannot find table 0."

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0


Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.]
   System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +95
   LHS.RightColumn.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Saravanan\Saravanan\Saravanan\LHS\LHS\RightColumn.ascx.cs:33
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Please help me how to resolve this.
In Visual Studio this application is running fine.
But in IIS it is showing this error.
Please help me in this

Comment: LHS.RightColumn.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Saravanan\Saravanan\Saravanan\LHS\LHS\RightColumn.ascx.cs:33

...And what is line 33?

Comment: @aquinas - I bet it is `...tables[0]...` where `tables` is `DataTableCollection`. The question is - how is this collection being filled?

Comment: Aquinas: I too dont know from where this path is displayed. In error message it is displaying like this. But there is no path like this in my system

Comment: strange that the `there is no path like this in the system` it must be. As the error is showing. The problem could be you have not give the right virtual path for you application.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error some weeks back and it occurred because the **web.config file was incorrect**. The **database information was invalid**. Hopefully, this will help you.

Comment: i have given correct database details in web.config. I verified but still same error is coming